# Is there a way to force java to ignore an Index out of bounds exception

Tags: matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

If, say, I want to iterate through a matrix and check the contents at the positions around the one I'm at, is there a way to check all those positions, and should one or more of them be out of bounds, it just skips that part and moves on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's advisable for most situations, in fact it is known to be bad Java practice, but you can use `try` and do nothing about exceptions. 
The whole issue with doing this though, is you can find yourself stuck trying to determine what an error is for eons of time and it turns out being something you could have handled with `catch`

Comment: Another problem is a performance hit. It is usually faster, easier to read and more maintainable to check array bounds using an if clause.

Comment: That as well. Really, `try`'s should be caught!

Comment: *"trys should be caught"* - I've no idea what you mean by that.  Please clarify.

Comment: @StephenC I just realized that statement really doesn't make any sense, yeah. I was just alluding to the fact that in most cases `try` should be followed by `catch` to handle exceptions, or at the very least the exceptions should be handled somewhere. *Unrelated to this question. but* I see a lot of questions from people  who's code is producing errors, so they wrap it all in a `try` statement to "fix" the errors, then cannot grasp why there code is not functioning properly. Hence, *try's should be caught*.

Comment: Actually I disagree with both of those propositions.  1) There are sound reasons to use `try` without a catch; e.g. resource management. 2) Catching immediately is often a bad idea.  3) In some cases, it is inadvisable to catch the exception at all.  For most (unexpected) unchecked exceptions, the best strategy is often to let the application die.

Comment: @StephenC That is all true, which is why I said *in most cases*, why I said that they should *usually* be handled *somewhere*, and I assumed we were speaking about ignoring exceptions, as in my example of people wrapping code in `try` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `try-catch` and this will catch the exception.

```
try {
// Your code where the exception is thrown should be placed here
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it's better to catch IndexOutOfBoundsException or, if possible, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use if else to check if the index I'm about to go to lies in the range, if not, I skip it.
This kind of situation usually occurs when you're trying to iterate a portion of a 2-D matrix using given values. Here is a good example when this kind of situation might occur.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/university-codesprint-3/challenges/erupting-volcanoes/problem

Answer (score 0):

Make the matrix two rows and columns wider.  That makes it so there are elements to index.  Put a value like zero on the edges so that they don't have an effect on your calculation.  Your loops go 1 to n-2 instead of 0 to n-1